# SVN checkout interrupt and then update

Tags: svn, interrupt

I want to interrupt the SVN checkout, can I get the rest of the file using SVN up later? It is not possible to checkout from the starch. Are there any alternatives for my problem ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no alternative. Your local checkout is corrupt, not partially checked out.

Comment: What's your use case for "wanting" to stop the checkout in this way? There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do that doesn't require stopping it in an unclean way.

Comment: @alroc, imagine a huge binary repo, which takes hours to checkout. you just need to reboot or get some disk/network bandwidth for another task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just clean locks and update your repo:

**Example:**

```
svn co http://some-repo/path/to/trunk
# Ctrl+C pressed
# cleaning locks up
svn cleanup
# now downloading rest of working copy
svn up
```